# Mingw, wcout and locales

Tags: c++, windows, io, i18n

I've recently had to print some national symbols in windows console using `Mingw` and found, that I got nothing in the output, if I use wide strings.

So, I studied the problem and found out that it is locale problem. I was unable to find somewhere complete solution, so I had to write something, that seems to work.

So, I decided to publish it here for review, or may be I should publish it somewhere it it worth.

- I've tested in Mingw 4.7.0 using Russian locale.
- It should probably correctly convert wide strings to national OEM encoded strings.

*Code:*

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_LOCALE_H
#define CUSTOM_LOCALE_H

#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
#define CUSTOM_LOCALE_OVERRIDE override
#else 
#define CUSTOM_LOCALE_OVERRIDE
#endif

#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

namespace custom_locale
{

class CustomLocale : public std::codecvt <wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t> {
  public:
    explicit CustomLocale ( size_t r = 0 ) : std::codecvt <wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t> (r) {}

  protected:
    result do_in (state_type&, const char* from, const char* from_end, 
                  const char*& from_next, wchar_t* to, wchar_t* to_end, wchar_t*& to_next ) const CUSTOM_LOCALE_OVERRIDE
    {
        std::size_t size = from_end - from;
        std::size_t buffer_size = to_end - to;
        std::size_t written = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_OEMCP, 0, from, size, to, buffer_size);
        to_next = to + written;
        if (written == 0) {
            return error;
        }
        else if (written != buffer_size) {
            return partial;
        }
        else {
            return  ok;
        }
    }

    result do_out (state_type&, const wchar_t* from, const wchar_t* from_end, 
                   const wchar_t*& from_next, char* to, char* to_end, char*& to_next ) const CUSTOM_LOCALE_OVERRIDE
    {
        std::size_t size = from_end - from;
        std::size_t buffer_size = to_end - to;
        std::size_t written = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_OEMCP, 0, from, size, to, buffer_size, 0, 0);
        to_next = to + written;
        if (written == 0) {
            return error;
        }
        else if (written != buffer_size) {
            return partial;
        }
        else {
            return  ok;
        }
    }

    result do_unshift ( state_type&, char*, char*, char*& ) const CUSTOM_LOCALE_OVERRIDE { return ok; }
    int do_encoding () const throw () CUSTOM_LOCALE_OVERRIDE { return 1; }
    bool do_always_noconv () const throw () CUSTOM_LOCALE_OVERRIDE { return false; }

    int do_length ( state_type& state, const char* from, const char* from_end, size_t max ) const CUSTOM_LOCALE_OVERRIDE 
    {
      return std::codecvt <wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>::do_length ( state, from, from_end, max );
    }

    int do_max_length () const throw () CUSTOM_LOCALE_OVERRIDE
    {
      return std::codecvt <wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>::do_max_length ();
    }
};

inline void init()
{
    std::locale loc ( std::locale(), new CustomLocale() );
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio (false);
    std::wcout.imbue(loc);
    std::wcin.imbue(loc);
} 

}

#endif
```

*Example:*

```
#include "custom_locale.h"

int main ()
{
    custom_locale::init();    
    std::wstring s(L"привет");
    std::wcout << s << '\n';
    std::wstring u; 
    std::wcin >> u;
    s += L' ' + u;
    std::wcout << s << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a somewhat old question, but I have an alternative that may work for this.  Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387054/how-can-i-use-stdimbue-to-set-the-locale-for-stdwcout), if you turn off the synchronization with the underlying `stdio`, you can use `imbue` to set the locale for both `wcout` and `wcin`:

```
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    // this code turns off the sync with stdio
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    // now create the appropriate locale without setting the global one
    std::locale ru("ru_RU.utf8");
    // use imbue to allow the Russian words to be properly displayed
    std::wcout.imbue(ru);
    // ... and input
    std::wcin.imbue(ru);

    // the rest of the code is essentially unchanged from the original
    std::wstring s(L"привет");
    std::wcout << s << '\n';
    std::wstring u; 
    std::wcin >> u;
    s += L' ' + u;
    std::wcout << s << '\n';
 }
```

Using it in this way means that no custom class is required.

Comment: Does it work with default windows console settings (code page 866 for ru)?

Comment: After doing some thorough testing, no, it does not work with that.  I'll work on this further to see if I can at least simplify what you've already done (which I can also verify works).

Comment: this does not work with `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++`